# Feature extraction in 3D gesture recognition for HMM with Kinect data

Tags: c#, algorithm, kinect, gesture-recognition, feature-extraction

I have a set of `3D` points mapped onto `[0, 1]` segments. These points represent simple gestures like circles, waving etc. Now I want to use `Hidden Markov Models` to recognize my gestures. First step is to extract features for `(X, Y, Z)` data. I tried to search something useful and found a couple examples: `SIFT`, `SURF`, some kind of `Fast Fourier Transform` etc.

I'm confused which one I should use in my project. I want to recognize gestures using data from Kinect controller, so I don't need to track joints algorithmically.

Comment: So no one can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to implement HMM for gesture recognition a year or two ago for a paper on different Machine Learning methods. I came across [Accord .NET Framework](https://code.google.com/p/accord/) which helps implement many of those I was looking into, including HMM. It's fairly easy to use and its creator is active on the forums.

To train the HMM I created a Kinect application that would start recording a gesture once a body part was stationary for 3 seconds, it would then record all the points to an output file until said part stopped for 3 seconds again. I then selected the best attempts at the gestures I wanted to train and used them as my training set.

If you are new to Kinect Gesture Recognition and don't **need** to use HMM I would suggest maybe looking into Template Matching as it's a lot simpler and I found it can be very effective for simple gestures.

Comment: Do you have your implementation yet? Can you share it in some way? I would be grateful! :) If you can, my e-mail: nick0n8@gmail.com - thanks for the answer!

Comment: I will contact you from my private account with some pointers sometime soon :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a similar problem. So far the best material, that I have found is Kinect Toolbox from David Catuhe. Has some basic code for gesture recognition, Kinect data recording and replay.

You can start reading here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/07/04/gestures-and-tools-for-kinect.aspx

Comment: I need to create a complete gesture detector using different algorithms which I have to describe formally afterall, so I can't use that lib. And the code itself won't tell me enought. So I'd love to read about some algorithms and implement them myself. It's my graduate project. So if you could point me some good algorithm for feature extraction that works pretty fast and will be easy for use in `HMM-based` gesture recognition. I will be grateful:)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a [trained] Support Vector Machine?

See: LibSVN Library http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/

The idea would be to define your gesture as a n-dimensional training problem. Then simply train for each gesture (multiple classification SVM). Once trained you map any user gesture as N-dimensional vector and attempt to classify it with the trained model.